# Passing options to Python executable in non-interactive mode

Tags: python

I would like to pass some options to Python (version 2.6) every time, not just in interactive mode.  Is there a file I can put such commands in?

EDIT: Specifically, I'm wanting to silence the Deprecation warnings.

Comment: Deprecation warnings don't work as they should in Python.  End-users should never see them, only developers: they should default off, not on, analogous to how C deprecations show up at compile or link-time, not runtime.

Comment: I'm in total agreement.  Obviously we all want libraries to work in python 3.x, but i should not have to see warnings _from imported libraries_  all the time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#!/usr/bin/python` line at the beginning of a Python script under Linux can be used to also pass options to the interpreter.

There are also a number of modules imported whenever Python starts up.  On my system, a likely candidate for modification to set options in the manner suggested by other posters are here:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sitecustomize.py
```

If you simply put this code in that file:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)
```

it will turn off deprecation warnings for everything always, which may not be what you want.  You could instead put in code that would check your own `PYTHONNODEPRECATIONWARNING` environment variable so you had more control.

After [finding a reference to sitecustomize.py in Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html#d0e24009) and this [reference to the sitecustomize module in the Python 2.6 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html), I think that file is your best bet for what you want.  In Python 2.6, with its user specific site-packages directory it's possible to set this up on a per-user basis, though you may want to find any system-wide sitecustomize.py file and either copy it into yours or find a way to explicitly import it in yours.

Comment: Brilliant, and thank you very much.  I think this is how I'll roll , and I'll turn it on for a ( dare I say it) "use strict;" effect

Comment: Glad you liked the answer.  :-)  I'm sort of amused that people still want to mod Mr. 63.9k up even though his answer clearly doesn't answer your question.  He must have quite the fan club.  :-)

Comment: How can this be implemented in Python3?

Comment: @ZERO - That's a good question. Have you tried the suggestions here?

Comment: `sitecustomize.py` is not executed.

Comment: @Velkan - Way back when I originally answered this question, I remember testing it. Has this changed in Python3?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the options can be passed in as environment variables -- do `python -h` to see the list:

```
$ py26 -h|grep PYTH
-B     : don't write .py[co] files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
-d     : debug output from parser; also PYTHONDEBUG=x
-E     : ignore PYTHON* environment variables (such as PYTHONPATH)
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
-O     : optimize generated bytecode slightly; also PYTHONOPTIMIZE=x
-s     : don't add user site directory to sys.path; also PYTHONNOUSERSITE
-u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
PYTHONSTARTUP: file executed on interactive startup (no default)
PYTHONPATH   : ':'-separated list of directories prefixed to the
PYTHONHOME   : alternate <prefix> directory (or <prefix>:<exec_prefix>).
PYTHONCASEOK : ignore case in 'import' statements (Windows).
PYTHONIOENCODING: Encoding[:errors] used for stdin/stdout/stderr.
```

Are you concerned with other flags that can't be set via environment variables?

PS the `PYTHONINSPECT=x` is the equivalent of `-i` (the `grep` cut that info because it comes on the immediately *previous* line;-).

Comment: I am, in fact concerned with other variables than those.  I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `~/.pythonrc.py?` It is listed in the Python man page with the following description:

> User-specific initialization file
>   loaded by the user module; not used by
>   default or by most applications.

I'm not sure what it means by the 'user' module but I think it's worth a shot to try this.

EDIT: It looks like you have to `import user` in your python scripts and then Python will automatically execute this ~/.pythonrc.py file upon startup (and not just in interactive mode). This should work in Python version < 3.0. 
http://docs.python.org/library/user.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I don't quite understand exactly what your question is, but, you might try:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)
```

So, this might not really answer the question.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know about this, and this helped me give a better answer to the OPs problem.