# Python startup script

Tags: python, startup

I would like to execute a script `work.py` in Python, after executing some initialization script `init.py`.

If I were looking for an interactive session, executing `python -i init.py` or setting `PYTHONSTARTUP=/path/to/init.py` would do the trick, but I am looking to execute another script.

Since this is a generic case which occurs often (`init.py` sets environment and so is the same all of the time), I would highly prefer not referencing `init.py` from `work.py`. How could this be done? Would anything change if I needed this from a script instead of from the prompt?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How does `work` depend on `init`?  Could you just do `python -c 'import init; import work'` ? -- or maybe less elegantly, `python -c 'execfile("init.py"); execfile("work.py")'`

Comment: `work` needs `init` to be executed before it. What you are suggesting may work (will try it now) but it's hardly ideal -- I need something like this every time I run a python script.

I could alias or create a shell command to reference it the usual way, e.g. `py work.py` where `py()` would be a defined shell command, but that will cause other issues.

I'd much prefer a clean way of always executing same init script if there is one...

Comment: So, (just to be clear), you want to globally define a script (`init.py`) to be called prior to anything else when starting up python as if your were doing something like `cat init.py main.py | python` completely independent of what file `main.py` actually is?

Comment: Related: [Passing options to Python executable in non-interactive mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2078752/95735)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More generally than in the accepted answer of C0deH4cker, this is discussed in the Python manual in [Section 2.2.5 - Cusomization Modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-customization-modules). The basic idea is, to get the location of the special start-up script, one needs to execute the following Python code, e.g. from the interactive session of the interpreter:

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getusersitepackages()
'/home/user/.local/lib/python3.2/site-packages'
```

The output should be exactly such a location, in the file `sitecustomize.py`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it is more portable.

Comment: Running `python -m site` (works on both Python 2 and Python 3) shows this info (look for line starting with `USER_SITE:`) and much more. For the `USER_BASE` and `USER_SITE` directories, it even checks whether the directories exist or not.

Answer (score 7):

Python has a special script that is run on startup. On my platform it is located at `/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/sitecustomize.py` IIRC. So, you could either put init.py in that directory alongside a sitecustomize.py script that imports it, or just paste the content of init.py in the sitecustomize.py.

Comment: couldn't make it work - put `init.py` into `/path/to/python/site-packages/site-customize.py` (directory existed, file did not) and see no changes to the previous state.

Comment: Oops, its sitecustomize.py (without hyphen). Editing answer.

Comment: thank you, that worked like magic. I wish you could do this without hacking though. For now, unless anything qualitatively better appears, I will gladly accept your answer. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It looks like `sitecustomize.py` and `usercustomize.py` modules are executed not in the same namespace in which interpreter runs subsequent scripts so it's not possible to modify global environment the same way it's possible in the [interactive startup file](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interactive-startup-file). I'd be glad to be corrected if it's possible.