# CPython: Why does a 3-line script require far more than 3 cycles in the interpreter to execute?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

I just watched [this Youtube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=LhadeL7_EIU) about CPython Internals by Philip Guo, I am puzzled at one thing.

At 25:55, he modifies the C source of CPython by inserting `printf(“hello\n”)` at the start of the endless loop which runs all the byte code instructions; you can do the same by:

- Downloading the Python 2.7 C source code
- Open the file `Python/ceval.c`
- Find the start of the endless evaluation loop, `for (;;) {`
- Add the line `printf('hello\n');` as the first line of the endless loop.
- Run `configure` and `make` to build the Python binary.

He writes a 3 line test.py:

```
X = 1
Y = 2
print X + Y
```

The puzzle is, when he runs test.py with the modified interpreter, how come there are so many “hello” before we see “3”?

That 3 line code should compile to just a few byte code instructions, load value 1, load value 2 and the instruction to call print, so I would imagine when it comes to execute the byte code compiled from test.py, we should see just a few "hello".

So the compiler actually generates many internal byte code instructions before compiling the external Python script?

Comment: You may have a site package. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737010/5509575 Also, there are many internal commands. Try looking for the output of `print 3` instead of doing math first.

Comment: No, Python doesn't insert bytecodes beyond what is needed for the code you compile. You can use the `dis` module to see what bytecode is generated.

Comment: Please include enough details to reproduce the behavior you're asking about **inside the question text itself**, as described in the first "some questions are still off-topic" bullet point at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. When someone needs to follow a link to understand a question, that means that question could become useless if the link breaks / external content is removed / etc; our goal is to build a knowledgebase that lasts.

Comment: It would be interesting to add `print "start test"` to the top of that and see how many hellos are between the prints.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: to reproduce: grab the Python 2.7 source code, edit the `ceval.c` file and add a `printf('hello\n')` line in the evaluation loop (right after the `for (;;)` line). Compile, use it to run the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons you see so many `hello`s printed:

- Python doesn't have a special bytecode for every possible Python statement. Instead statements will use a *combination* of bytecodes.
- The Python interpreter imports a series of Python modules *just to start running*.  You can run a regular Python interpreter with the `-v` switch to see what is imported each time. Each module consists of multiple statements, so there is quite some bytecode to go through before you get to the little script you are running.

If I put those 3 lines into `test.py` and use my unmodified Python 2.7 binary to run that, with the `-v` switch, I see:

```
$ python2.7 -v test.py
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /..../lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /..../lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /..../lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
import encodings # directory /..../lib/python2.7/encodings
# /..../lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /..../lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /..../lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /..../lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /..../lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.15 (default, May  7 2018, 17:08:03)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
3
# -- clean-up output omitted --
```

Each `import ...` line in there references either a built-in module (part of the Python binary, implemented in C) or a `.pyc` bytecode cache file. There are 17 such files being imported *before the script code even is run*.

The 3 lines of code in the main script translate to a further 9 bytecode instructions:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile(r'''\
... X = 1
... Y = 2
... print X + Y
... ''', '', 'exec'))
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (X)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (Y)

  4          12 LOAD_NAME                0 (X)
             15 LOAD_NAME                1 (Y)
             18 BINARY_ADD
             19 PRINT_ITEM
             20 PRINT_NEWLINE
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

(I ignored the 2 bytecodes at the end, encoding an extra `return None` that's not really applicable to a module).