# How to reuse preamble in python?

Tags: python

I have a routine for my work and basically writing the same header over and over again.

A minimal example could looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(personal_path)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import personal_modul
```

I am getting sick of copy- and pasting it all the time and was wondering if there is a way to reuse the preamble? Is this even possible?

Is there a one liner to add all the imports?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing options to Python executable in non-interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078752/passing-options-to-python-executable-in-non-interactive-mode)

Comment: This is helping, but I was actually looking for a one liner to include the imports if I need them. This answer suggests that I enable them by default.

Comment: Maybe you can add a condition with an environment variable which should be set ?

Comment: You can stick these lines in a module and do something like `from my_module import *`. Whether you should do this or not is a different question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat clean way would be to put this into its own module from which you could access it all e.g.

```py
# boilerplate.py
__all__ = ['pd', 'np', 'personal_module']
import sys
sys.path.append(personal_path)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import personal_module
```

and in your script

```py
from boilerplate import *
```

which would put all the stuff in boilerplate's `__all__` in the local namespace.

A less portable and maintainable alternative would be to use [the site hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site) and more specifically [the user site feature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE).  Given you're just... appending what looks like a hardcoded path to your sys.path, portability doesn't seem like much of a concern here anyway.